# making an object rotate according to the cursor position

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a game in which a cannons barrel is lifted or lowerd according to the cursor's position.

Here is the code I inserted inside the Barrel mc:

```
import flash.events.Event;
var hypotenuse,ratio,angleRad,angleDeg:Number;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,spin);

function spin (e:Event):void{
    trace(mouseX+ " " + mouseY);
hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((mouseX)*(mouseX)+(mouseY)*(mouseY));
ratio = (Math.abs(mouseX))/hypotenuse;
angleRad = Math.asin(ratio);
angleDeg = angleRad*180/Math.PI;
if(mouseX >= 0 && mouseY <= 0 ){
    this.rotation = angleDeg;
}
if(mouseX >= 0 && mouseY > 0){
    this.rotation = (90-angleDeg)*2;
}
if(mouseX < 0 && mouseY > 0){
    this.rotation = angleDeg + 180;
}
if( mouseX < 0 && mouseY <= 0){
    this.rotation = (90-angleDeg)*2;
}
}
```

For some reason the barrel is just jerking around and not even in the direction where the mouse is at.. =/ I would love some advice or maybe a different coding suggestions
this is a problem I'v been trying to solve for a while now and i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Like the 2 others said, the best way would be to use atan2. Since you even traced the result, my guess is that the mouseX and mouseY gives you the position relative to your cannon.

Once that is assumed, you can just call `angleRad = atan2(mouseY, mouseX)`

This will give you an angle between 0 and Math.PI. `degAngle = angleRad/Math.PI*180` will give it in degrees

from there, you can test if the angle is between 0 and 180 (mouseY>0), and it will give something like this :

```
if mouseY<0 then
    angleDeg-=180; //since rotation is optimized for -180<angle<180 afaik
end if
this.rotation = angleDeg;
```

<strike>the jerking was probably due to `(90-angleDeg)*2` which basically translates to 180-2*angleDeg</strike>

EDIT : Are you certain the jerking isn't caused by the x/y coordinates of your object changing based on rotation? Your diagonals will be larger than your sides, so rotating the sprite may alter the X/Y, which will calculate a new angle, which will make it rotate, which... will make it jerk.

You should always use central points (x+width/2 and y+height/2) for maths in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

To get the angle between two points, calculate the x and y distance

```
ydiff = y2 - y1
xdiff = x2 - x1
```

then find the `atan2` of `ydiff` and `xdiff`:

`Math.atan2(ydiff,xdiff)`

Bam! You just got the angle between point 1 and point 2. It's probably in radians, so convert first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the angle between the horizon (default: eastwards) and line between barrel base and mouse position. So, first you get barrel position relative to some unmoving and horizon-aligned entity (hint: stage), then you get mouse position relative to stage as well, then subtract Ys and Xs, call `Math.atan2()` and convert from radians to degrees. Should do. Code is from within Barrel:

```
var barrelPoint:Point=this.LocalToGlobal(new Point());
var angle:Number=Math.atan2(e.stageY-barrelPoint.y,e.stageX-barrelPoint.x);
this.rotation=angle*180/math.PI;
```